# How to use PCLStorage in Portable class library?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone, portable-class-library

I have a Portable class library which I am going to use for Windows 8 and phone apps. So I created a common viewmodeland, and now I want to handle storage functionality in viewmodels. I found a PCLStorage package which is used to deal with this scenario.

I have a code like this on Windows 8 and now I want to write this in PCL using PCLStorage.

```
 public static object LoadSettings(string key)
    {            
        if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            if (Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key] != null)
            {
                return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[key];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I found a way, I have created a interface for Storage used in viewmodel. And have created a class to handle storage for phone and metro in respective projects. When I am creating a object of MainViewModel I am passing storage object also.

So I want to know, is this right?

Comment: can you tell me why you use the PLC storage and not the Windows.Storage Namespace? or else the isolated storage of the phone (System.IO.Storage) ?

Comment: Windows.Storage is not accessible in PCL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest pattern would be to Register the current-platform-defendant-implementation  within the container bootstrapper on the 'specific' 'shell' for platform and get the dependenciy in the constructor
Or simply skip the IoC thing and instantiate stuff manually

```
using MyInfrastructureAssembly.Interfaces;
public MyApp: App // MyNewPlatFormApp
{
public override Initiaze()
{
    var bootsrapper =  new Boostrapper(MyIoC.Current);
}
}
public class Bootsrapper: TheBootStrapperOfMyIoc
{ 
   public Bootsrapper(IocContainer container)
   {
    Container = container;
   }
   public override Register()
   {
     Container.Register<IMyAbstractedService,MyPlatformDependantService>();   
   }
} 
MyPlatformDependantService : IMyAbstractedService 
{
public object Get(); // IMyAbstractedService.Get()
}
public class MyViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
IMyService  MyService {get;set;}

MyViewModel(IMyAbstractedService myServcice)
{       
    MyService = myService;
}

public object Thing // LazyThing provided by IMyAbstractedService 
{
    get
    { 
        if(_thing!=null)
        return _thing;
        return _thing = GetIt();
    }
    set 
    {
        if(Equals(value,_thing)) return;
        _thing = value;
        base.NotifyMagicalChanges()
    }
}
    public void GetIt()
{       
    MyServcie.Get();
}
}
```

Static Version : Runs on [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
enter code here
private async void CheckIfExist()
    {
        try
        {
            var isoStore = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

            var folder = await isoStore.CreateFolderAsync("xxx", 
CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);                

            ExistenceCheckResult result = await  isoStore.CheckExistsAsync("xxx");

            switch (result)
            {
                case (ExistenceCheckResult.FolderExists):
                    Console.WriteLine(":)"); break;
                case (ExistenceCheckResult.NotFound):
                    Console.WriteLine(":("); break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(":<");
        }
    }'
```

Comment: Everything flows over me, I am not such talented like you. So please explain it in detail or give some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a way, I have created a interface for Storage used in viewmodel. And have created a class to handle storage for phone and metro in respective projects. When I am creating a object of MainViewModel I am passing storage object also. So i want to know that Is this right?

Yes, this is a good solution.  Dan's answer is basically just the same thing but using an IoC container.

You can also try the [Xam.Plugins.Settings](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xam.PCL.Plugins) library, which basically does for settings what PCL Storage does for File IO.